# Ruby: check if a .zip file exists, and extract

Tags: ruby

2 small questions to create the effect I'm looking for. 
How do I check if a file exists within a directory with the extension of .zip?
If it does exist I need to make a folder with the same name as the .zip without the .zip extension for the folder.
Then I need to extract the files into the folder.

Secondly, what do I do if there are more than one .zip files in the folder?

I'm doing something like this and trying to put it into ruby

```
`mkdir fileNameisRandom`
`unzip fileNameisRandom.zip -d fileNameisRandom`
```

On a similar post I found something like

```
Dir.entries("#{Dir.pwd}").select {|f| File.file? f}
```

which I know checks all files within a directory and makes sure they are a file.
The problem is I don't know how to make sure that it is only an extension of .zip

Also, I found the Glob function which checks the extension of a filename from: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html
How do I ensure the file exists in that case, and if it doesn't I can print out an error then.

From the comment I now have

```
if Dir['*.zip'].first == nil #check to see if any exist
    puts "A .zip file was not found"
elsif Dir['*.zip'].select {|f| File.file? f} then #ensure each of them are a file
    #use a foreach loop to go through each one
    Dir['*.zip'].select.each do |file|
        puts "#{file}"
    end  ## end for each loop
end
```

Comment: Dir['*.zip'].select{|f| File.file? f} may help you get started

Comment: Ok, tested that part and now it is working.  Now I just need to figure out how to use it in an array, and get the names of the zip files without extension. +1 to you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way of doing this with less branching:

```
# prepare the data
zips= Dir['*.zip'].select{ |f| File.file? } 

# check if data is sane
if zips.empty?
  puts "No zips"
  exit 0 # or return
end

# process data   
zips.each do |z|

end
```

This pattern is easier to follow for fellow programmers.

You can also do it using a ruby gem called `rubyzip`

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rubyzip'
```

run bundle

unzip.rb:

```
require 'zip'

zips= Dir['*.zip'].select{ |f| File.file? } 

if zips.empty?
  puts "No zips"
  exit 0 # or return
end

zips.each do |zip|
  Zip::File.open(zip) do |files|
    files.each do |file|
       # write file somewhere 
       # see here https://github.com/rubyzip/rubyzip
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally pieced together different information from tutorials and used @rogerdpack and his comment for help.
    require 'rubygems/package'
    #require 'zlib'
    require 'fileutils'

```
#move to the unprocessed directory to unpack the files
#if a .tgz file exists
#take all .tgz files
#make a folder with the same name
#put all contained folders from .tgz file inside of similarly named folder
#Dir.chdir("awaitingApproval/")


if Dir['*.zip'].first == nil #check to see if any exist, I use .first because Dir[] returns an array
    puts "A .zip file was not found"
elsif Dir['*.zip'].select {|f| File.file? f} then #ensure each of them are a file
    #use a foreach loop to go through each one
    Dir['*.zip'].select.each do |file|
        puts "" #newlie for each file
        puts "#{file}" #print out file name
        #next line based on `mkdir fileNameisRandom`
        `mkdir #{Dir.pwd}/awaitingValidation/#{ File.basename(file, File.extname(file)) }`
        #next line based on `unzip fileNameisRandom.zip -d fileNameisRandom`
        placement = "awaitingValidation/" + File.basename(file, File.extname(file))
        puts "#{placement}"
        `sudo unzip #{file} -d #{placement}`
        puts "Unzip complete"
    end  ## end for each loop
end
```